# Issue with Xaml (I guess)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) project for my school, and what I'm trying to do is really simple. I'm just trying to open a new page using:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

The problem is that if i use that code on Button Click event the code always works.. but If I use exactly the same code from a MenuFlyoutItem Click event:

```
    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

the App Crash. Opening the App.g.i.cs Tab at this point.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)        global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

I'm sorry if this has already been asked before but I could not find anything on the web.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you give us the details of the exception? When the debugger opens App.g.i.cs, either hover your mouse on the "e" variable or type "e.ToString()" in the "Immediate" window of Visual Studio

Comment: Look at the Windows8 equivalant of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (I don't remember off the top of my head, sorry). The flyout menu items have some "unique" threading concerns if I recall correctly.

Comment: I don't know why, but seems that the problem now is fixed after Changing the code into this 
BottomAppBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
                Frame.GoBack();
            else
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

Anyway thank you very much for your help!!